# How to use twitteR to find specific subject?

Tags: r, twitter

I just use twitteR to find some specific subjects：

```
searchTwitter("MAKE UP FOR EVER", n=1000, lang="en")
```

It returns some tweets that do not contain this string.

> [1] there's nothing you could ever do to make up for that.
>   [2] 20. no matter how many excuses you make up for doing it that day,
>   none of them will be valid. ever.
>   [3] if i'm ever in the market for a make up bag. now i know where to
>   go. x

How could I get all tweets that contain only the requested subject?

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply searchTwitter command with exact PHRASE, not WORDS.
For this you need to put additional "", i.e.:

searchTwitter("\"MAKE UP FOR EVER\"", n = 1000, lang = "en")

Backlash is needed in order to escape following double quotes and let R parse them correctly. More on this at: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's search API also **does not guarantee** that it'll return every tweet ever posted recently. See [official documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search):

> Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is
>   focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets
>   and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for
>   completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead